# ubuntu bash printing result in system with extra ""

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal

Why do my result for A have `""` and only capture first word while my B is fine?

File: sample.txt

```
Amos Tan:Sunny Day:22.5:3:2 
Jason Ong:Rainy Day:20.5:3:2 
Bryan Sing:Cloudy Day:29.5:3:2
```

Code in terminal:

```
cat ./sample.txt | while read A B
do 
    title=`echo “$A” | cut -f 1 -d ":"`
    echo "Found $title"
    author=`echo “$B” | cut -f 2 -d ":"`
    echo "Found $author
done
```

Results:

```
Found “Amos”
Found Sunny Day
Found “Jason”
Found Rainy Day
Found “Bryan”
Found Cloudy Day
```

Answer (score 4):

This line is the problem:

```
cat ./sample.txt | while read A B
```

It is reading first word into `A` and rest of the line in variable `B`.

You can better use:

```
while read -r line
do 
    title=$(echo "$line" | cut -f 1 -d ":")
    echo "Found title=$title"
    author=$(echo "$line" | cut -f 2 -d ":")
    echo "Found author=$author"
done < ./sample.txt
```

Or simply use `awk`:

```
awk -F : '{printf "title=%s, author=%s\n", $1, $2}' sample.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it helps. But i have another qn about the logic. my title and author are combined primary key. If user enter same title and author then prompt user to enter again else continue other inputs. I tried myself but is not working.

Comment: book_title=""
book_author=""
book_price=0.0
echo "Please enter a book title: "
read book_title
echo "Please enter a book author: "
read book_author
while read -r line
do 
 title=$(echo "$line" | cut -f 1 -d ":")
 author=$(echo "$line" | cut -f 2 -d ":")
 if [ "$title" = "$book_title" ] & [ "$author" = "$book_author" ]
 then
  echo "User exist please re-enter title and author"
  echo "Please enter a book title: "
  read book_title
  echo "Please enter a book author: "
  read book_author
 else
  echo "Please enter the price of the book: "
  read book_price
 fi
done < ./BookDB.txt

Comment: Can you post this attempted script in question since it is impossible to understand from comments section.